# Show databases working though show_dB_priv is set to N in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

We don't want `show databases` to be run from a particular user.
We have granted only, Select, Insert, Update, delete privileges on our DB. However we are able to run `show databases`.

How can we restrict that command in Mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

---

You need to edit the `skip-show-database` environment variable, either at startup or better yet edit the options file.

my options file is at /etc/mysql/my.cnf

add the line `skip-show-database` below `[mysqld]`

users with the `show_db_priv` permission can use `show databases;` however users without the permission cannot.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-show-database

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_show_database

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html